# Prove: $\omega(f,P)\leq \omega(f,Q)+2nL*\lambda(P)$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Let $P=\{x_{1},...,x_{k}\}$ and $P\subseteq Q$ a refinement of the partition $P$ which is due to adding one point $Q=P\cup\{y\}$, In this case both partition are the same except of on interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ such that $[x_{i-1},x_{i}] \notin Q$ in it place there are $[x_{i-1},y]$ and$[y,x_{i}]$.

Now, $\omega(f,P)$ and $\omega(f,Q)$ only differ in two elements where $\omega_{i}\Delta x$ is part of $\omega(f,P)$ the correspond to $\omega'(y-x_{i-1})$ and $\omega''(x_{i}-y)$ which is part of $\omega(f,Q)$

$$|\omega(f,P)-\omega(f,Q)|=|\omega_{i}\Delta x-\omega'(y-x_{i-1}-1)-\omega''(x_{i}-y)|=|(\omega_{i}-\omega')(y-x_{i-1}+(\omega_{i}-\omega'')(x_{i}-y)|\leq |\omega_{i}-\omega'|(y-x_{i-1})+|\omega_{i}-\omega''|(x_{i}-y)$$

Because $f$ is bounded by $L$ the three oscillations $\omega_{i},\omega',\omega''$ are bounded from above by $2L$, therefore:

$$|\omega(f,P)-\omega(f,Q)|\leq 2L(y-x_{i-1})+2L(x_{i}-y)=2l(x_{i}-x_{i-1})\leq 2L*\lambda(P)$$

And to finish the proof we will use induction.

**is the following equation is mandatory?**
$$ |\omega(f,P)-\omega(f,Q)|=|\omega_{i}\Delta x-\omega'(y-x_{i-1}-1)-\omega''(x_{i}-y)|=|(\omega_{i}-\omega')(y-x_{i-1})+(\omega_{i}-\omega'')(x_{i}-y)|$$

Or can we just write $$|\omega(f,P)-\omega(f,Q)|=|(\omega_{i}-\omega')(y-x_{i-1})+(\omega_{i}-\omega'')(x_{i}-y)|$$